# Summary spacing problem

Tags: vertical, alignment

Goodmorning, I'm trying without any success to vertically align the "abstract" word in the first page of my final thesis. I'm able to do it if I don't insert the "edit with latex" sentence but I'd like to keep it. Any suggestion?[image]

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper,oneside,openright]{book}

        \usepackage[italian]{babel} 
        \usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
        \usepackage{textcomp}
        \usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

        \usepackage[scaled=.90]{helvet}
        \usepackage{titlesec}
        \usepackage{guit}
        \usepackage{makeidx}
        \usepackage{lipsum}
        \usepackage{layaureo}
        \usepackage{emptypage}
        \usepackage{setspace}
        \usepackage{fancyhdr}
        \usepackage{graphicx}
        \usepackage{caption}
        \usepackage{pdfpages}
        \usepackage{float}
        \usepackage{adjustbox}
        \usepackage{longtable}
        \usepackage{tabu}
        \usepackage{pdflscape}
        \usepackage{makecell}
        \setcellgapes{2pt}
        \usepackage{array}
        \usepackage{dcolumn}
        \usepackage{amsthm} 
        \usepackage{amsfonts}
        \usepackage{eufrak}
        \usepackage{mathrsfs}
        \usepackage{amsmath,amssymb} 
        \usepackage{siunitx} 
        \usepackage{nicefrac}
        \usepackage{xfrac} 
        \usepackage{varwidth}
        \usepackage{tasks} 
        \usepackage{booktabs,cellspace}
        \setlength\cellspacetoplimit{5pt} 
        \setlength\cellspacebottomlimit{5pt}
        \usepackage{ragged2e}
        \usepackage{changepage}
        \usepackage{tabularx}
        \usepackage{subfig}
        \usepackage{cancel}
        \usepackage{dblfloatfix}
        \usepackage[colorlinks=true,allbordercolors=white]{hyperref}
        \usepackage[all]{hypcap}
        \usepackage{cleveref}
        \usepackage[inline]{enumitem}
        \usepackage[autostyle,italian=guillemets]{csquotes} 
        \usepackage[bibstyle=authoryear,citestyle=authoryear-comp,backend=biber,useprefix=true]{biblatex}
        \usepackage{url}
        \usepackage{multirow}
        \usepackage{rotating}
        \usepackage{listings}
        \usepackage{pgfplots}
        \pgfplotsset{compat=newest}
        \usepackage{colortbl}
        \usepackage{xcolor}
        \usepackage[italian]{varioref}
        \usepackage{bookmark} 
        \usepackage{verbatim}
        \usepackage{pict2e}[2009/06/01]
        \usepackage{wrapfig}
        \usepackage{wasysym}
        \usepackage{numprint}
        \usepackage{tikz}


        %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%  envinronment definition  %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
        \makeatletter
        \if@titlepage
        \newenvironment{abstract}{%
            \titlepage
            \null\vfil
            \@beginparpenalty\@lowpenalty
            \begin{center}
                \bfseries \abstractname
                \@endparpenalty\@M
        \end{center}}%
        {\par\vfil\null\endtitlepage}
        \else
        \newenvironment{abstract}{%
            \if@twocolumn
            \section*{\abstractname}%
            \else
            \small
            \begin{center}%
                {\bfseries \abstractname\vspace{-.5em}\vspace{\z@}}%
            \end{center}%
            \quotation
            \fi}
        {\if@twocolumn\else\endquotation\fi}
        \fi
        \makeatother

        %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%  end envinronment definition  %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

        \onehalfspacing
        \raggedbottom 



        \begin{document}
        \frontmatter
        \pagestyle{plain}
            \begin{abstract}
                \vfill

                \lipsum[1] 

                \mbox{}
                \vfill
                \centering
                {\large Edit with \LaTeX }\\

            \end{abstract}  
        \mainmatter

        \appendix

        \backmatter

        \end{document}\\
```

Comment: What do you mean with ‘vertically align’?

Comment: That I'd like to have the word "Summary" near to the text of the summary, to move the "summary" word below, in the center of the page.

Answer (score 1):

Use this code (simplified) in the body of the document:

```
    \frontmatter
    \pagestyle{plain}%
    \begin{abstract}

        \lipsum[1]
         \mbox{}
         \vfill
         \centering
         {\large Edit with \LaTeX }

        \end{abstract}

    \mainmatter

    \appendix

    \backmatter
```

and in the preamble, the definition of the `abstract` environment should begin with

```
        \titlepage
        \null\vfill
```

instead of

```
        \titlepage
        \null\vfil
```

[image]